# electron-packager and sqlite3 - Cannot find module when .exe is launched if packed in 32bit mode

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-packager, node-sqlite3

I am trying to build a simple electron app that uses sqlite3. I want to create an .exe with the help of electron-packager. But if I then run the .exe I get an error saying that the sqlite3 module cannot be found. Runnig my app directly from gitBash works perfectly fine though.
Here is my app:

main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('MyDB.db');



const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = electron;

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;
let currentlyOpenOffers = [];

app.on('ready', function(){
    //Create new Window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
        {
            width: 900,
            height: 700,
            webPreferences:{
                nodeIntegration:true,
                contextIsolation: false
            }
        });
    // Load html into window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'MainWindow.html'),
        protocol : 'file',
        shlashes: true
    }));
    // Quit app when closed
    mainWindow.on('closed', function(){
        app.quit();
    })

});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electron_with_sqlite3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . MyApp --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"MyApp\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.9",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0"
  }
}
```

I then ran:

- npm install --save sqlite3
- npm install --save-dev electron
- npm install --save-dev electron-packager
- npm run package-win

the result is then found at within the release-builds folder.

If I run the MyApp.exe there I get an error message:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module
'C:\Users\KLOUD\Desktop\Electron_With_SQLITE3\release-builds\MyApp...\node_sqlite3.node
```

What do I have to do to get the packed app .exe to work with sqite3 ?

I have read at various places that I would have to rebuild sqlite3 on my platform. Yet everything I found was not using electron-packager. So if somebody could explain to me how I could get this to work with electron-packager I would be very happy. Thanks

EDIT:
Thanks to cachique this is how it was solved for me:
Building the application for 64 bit by using "--arch=x64" in the parameters for electron packager.

```
 "package-win": "electron-packager . MyApp --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"MyApp\"",
```

Comment: Just a side note. You should install `electron` as a dev-dependency. Just like electron-packager.

Comment: From your build script you are making it 32 bit, which clearly has problems. But 64bit builds flawlessly. Do you really need it to be 32 bit these days ?

Comment: Also this [post](https://www.jviotti.com/2016/12/09/how-to-manually-package-an-electron-app-for-windows.html) helped a lot to understand electron packager process.

Comment: I am more than impressed. Thank you so much. Building a x64 app worked perfectly fine. No missing module, all good. Any idea why it works with x64?

Comment: I suppose when you install sqlite via npm is built for x64 architecture. But when you try to use it in a 32bit logically fails.
I tried to rebuild it for 32 bit using electron-builder but with no luck so far.

Comment: Can you please state somewhere in your post, better in the title, that the issue is when building 32bit module?